# onChange on React componet not changing state inside it's parent

Tags: reactjs, events, react-hooks, state, onchange

So I've created a text input component and imported it to another component.
The gave it a prop onChange and said that the state value should be set to e.target.value
but I think it doens't work this way.

here is what I did

```
function Input() {
  return (
    <input type="text"  />
  )
}


export default Input
```

---

then imported in here and put the onChange

```
 function RepositoryList() {
    const[repositories, setRepositories] = useState([]);
    const[search, setSearch]=useState('')

  

    const url = "https://api.adresss";
    useEffect(()=> {
        fetch(url)
        .then((response)=> response.json())
        .then(data => setRepositories(data))
    },[repositories])

  return (
     <>
     <ul>

     <Input onChange={(e)=>{setSearch(e.target.value)}}/>

     {repositories
     .filter((repos) =>  repos.name.includes(search) )
     .map(repository => {
         return <RepositoryItem key={repository.name} repo={repository}/>
     })}
    </ul>
    
    </> 
  )
}

export default RepositoryList
```

Comment: You need to pass the actual callback in Input component, read the docs for examples. `Input({onChange}) => {...}`

Answer (score 0):

pass onChange callback to input

```js
function Input(props) {
  return (
    <input type="text" onChange={props.onChange} />
  )
}


export default Input
```